# How to upload multiple files to be downloaded by contacts in frontend

Tags: joomla, files

I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.7. on Joomla for a Sport Club in which athletes have access to his licences, anual documents, reglaments, etc. from frontend.

In configuration we have added some custom fields to profiles, for example, "Licenses", and inside "Anual Sport License" and "Anual Federative License". For each license we have enabled the option to administrators to upload a file from backend that after, athletes can download in frontend.

The problem is when we update that files in the next season, previous file is deleted automatically and only the more recent stills, but we need that athletes can download all the files historial in every moment.

Can someone help us?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

see https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/custom-fields/
under Multiple record fieldsets. you can set (only for contacts) multiple field records. aftewards you can set how the content should be displayed. i think you can do that with files too.